# C# - Why I get LockRecursionException when using ReaderWriterLockSlim?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging, locking, streamwriter

I am working on a multi-threaded program. I'm trying to create a **simple logging system** with two types of logs: 'INFO' and 'ERROR'.
I created a class called 'Logger' and two static methods: Info and Error. I also created a static ReadWriterLockSlim so only one thread at a time can write to the log file.

The logging works for a while but after a few minutes I get this exception:

```
System.Threading.LockRecursionException: 'Recursive write lock acquisitions not allowed in this mode.'
```

Here's the Logger class code:

```
public class Logger
{
    const string filePath = "Log.txt";
    static private ReaderWriterLockSlim writeLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim();
    public static string Info(string log)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | INFO | " + log;
        writeLock.EnterWriteLock();
        using (StreamWriter writetext = File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            writetext.WriteLine(logMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
        writeLock.ExitWriteLock();
        return logMessage;
    }

    public static string Error(string log)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | ERROR | " + log;
        writeLock.EnterWriteLock();
        using (StreamWriter writetext = File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            writetext.WriteLine(logMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
        return logMessage;
    }

}
```

Hope someone can help me understand what I did wrong and how to fix it.
Thank you all in advance.

Comment: In your `Error` method, you enter the write lock but never exit it again. When that same thread tries to enter `Info` or `Error` and acquire the lock again, you'll get that exception. You need to make sure that you always release the lock after acquiring it (ideally using a try/catch, in case writing the message throws an exception)

Comment: Also, since you never read, what's the reason for having a reader/writer lock? This is a specialised lock which allows one reader or multiple writers at the same time. It doesn't look like you can have multiple writers at the same time, so you're not making use of the lock. From the code you posted, you could use a simple [`lock` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement)

Comment: As well as `Error` not releasing the lock, neither method uses a `try-finally` to ensure the lock is released if an exception is thrown whole writing to the log file. If an I/O exception occured randomly while writing a log entry, you'd leak the lock and cause the same issue.

Comment: @canton7 Yeah, I think it solves it. My bad.

Comment: @MartinCostello Thanks Martin. Can you show me an example of how I should have used try-finally? Also I took canton7 advice and changed the reader/writer lock to a simple lock() statement. How would you use try-finally with the lock() statement?

Thank you all!

Comment: @RonDeitch If you're using `lock` then you don't need to worry about `try-catch` as it's built-in for that use case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is in your `Error` method: it takes the lock, but doesn't release it again.

Also, you should really be using a `try/finally` when taking a lock. This ensures that if an exception is thrown when writing a log message, the lock is always released:

```
public static string Error(string log)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | ERROR | " + log;
    writeLock.EnterWriteLock();
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter writetext = File.AppendText(filePath))
        {
            writetext.WriteLine(logMessage);
            Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        writeLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
    return logMessage;
}
```

That said, a read/write lock is a specialised lock which allows a single writer or multiple readers to access a resource at the same time. You don't have any readers, so there's no point in using a read/write lock. Just use a normal lock:

```
public class Logger
{
    const string filePath = "Log.txt";
    private static readonly object lockObject = new object();
    public static string Info(string log)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | INFO | " + log;
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writetext = File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                writetext.WriteLine(logMessage);
                Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
            }
        }
        return logMessage;
    }

    public static string Error(string log)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string logMessage = DateTime.Now.ToString() + " | ERROR | " + log;
        lock (lockObject)
        {
            using (StreamWriter writetext = File.AppendText(filePath))
            {
                writetext.WriteLine(logMessage);
                Console.WriteLine(logMessage);
            }
        }
        return logMessage;
    }
}
```